# How to make Ajax request in Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Ajax request does not work in laravel

```
$(':button').click(function(){
    var commentText = $('#comment_input').val();

    $.post( "comment", {comment: commentText}, onAjaxSuccess );

    function onAjaxSuccess(data){
        $('#info').html(data);
    }
});
```

route

```
Route::post('/comment', ['as'=>'comment', 'uses' => 'CommentController@addComment' ] );
```

controller

```
public function addComment(Request $request){

    //$comment =  $request->input('comment');

    return Respons::json( Request::all() );
}
```

Ajax posted a request to add a comment. There is no response from the server, or the request does not reach the server.

Comment: Test it with Postman or curl.

Comment: have you taken care of CSRF token?

Comment: yes, i have token, but it stil dont work

Comment: Don't really know what I'm talking about, but is it supposed to be `Respons`? Or is it supposed to be `Response`?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?  Have you tried Axios?

Comment: This code has been copied, I changed it to `Response` and to return `return response()->json($comment);` but still nothing works